# Convert Yes/No/Null from SQL to True/False in a DataTable

Tags: c#, sql, sql-server, datatable

I have a Sql Database (which I have no control over the schema) that has a Column that will have the varchar value of "Yes", "No", or it will be null. For the purpose of what I am doing null will be handled as No.

I am programming in c# net 3.5 using a data table and table adapter to pull the data down. I would like to directly bind the column using a binding source to a check box I have in my program however I do not know how or where to put the logic to convert the string Yes/No/null to boolean True/False;

Reading a null from the SQL server and writing back a No on a update is acceptable behavior.

Any help is greatly appreciated.

EDIT --
This is being developed for windows.

Comment: What application are you developing windows, asp.net or silverlight?

Comment: I think it would matter with the data-binding.  Altering a select statement is easy, but this question seems to include data-binding that would correctly write back `Yes` and `No` to the db.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I originally used Dathan's solution however my checkbox would not push its updates to the data table it was bound to, while trying to solve that issue I found out about `Binding.Parse` and `Binding.Format` I now leave the query normal and use this:

```
Public Form1()
{
    InitializeComponent();
    cbxKeepWebInfinityChanges.DataBindings["Checked"].Parse += new ConvertEventHandler(cbxKeepWebInfinityChanges_Parse);
    cbxKeepWebInfinityChanges.DataBindings["Checked"].Format += new ConvertEventHandler(cbxKeepWebInfinityChanges_Format);
}

void cbxKeepWebInfinityChanges_Parse(object sender, ConvertEventArgs e)
{
    if ((bool)e.Value == true)
        e.Value = "Yes";
    else
        e.Value = "No";
}
void cbxKeepWebInfinityChanges_Format(object sender, ConvertEventArgs e)
{
    if ((string)e.Value == "Yes")
        e.Value = true;
    else
        e.Value = false;
}
```

Answer (score 9):

Modify the query that populates your `DataTable` to include the appropriate logic:

```
SELECT col1, col2, CAST(CASE YesNoNullCol WHEN 'yes' THEN 1 WHEN 'no' THEN 0 ELSE 0 END AS BIT) FROM SomeTable
```

**EDIT:** Forgot that you have to supply Insert / Update / Delete commands on DataAdapter as well.

In order to get commits to work using the above, you need to specify custom commands for performing updates to the DB:

```
SqlCommand insert_cmd = connection.CreateCommand();
insert_cmd.CommandText = "INSERT INTO SomeTable(col1, col2, YesNoNullCol) VALUES (@col1, @col2, CASE @yesnonullcol WHEN 1 THEN 'Yes' WHEN 0 THEN 'No' ELSE 'No' END)";
var yesno_col = insert_cmd.CreateParameter();
yesno_col.Name = "@yesnonullcol";
insert_cmd.Parameters.Add(col1_parm);
myAdapter.InsertCommand = insert_cmd;
```

And, of course, you need to provide parameters for `@col1` and `@col2` as well.  And then you need to create commands for update and delete if you want to support those operations.

Comment: this is the easy part.  He needs data-binding that will correctly write back to the db 'Yes' and 'No'.

Comment: If i put that in my query that populates it, the select works fine but the update does not include the changes.

Comment: @Scott apologies - I've updated the question (though, apologies again, I haven't compiled the code, I just wrote it, so there are probably syntax or logic errors).

Comment: I did like your solution the best but I found a better way while solving another problem.

Comment: @Scott fair enough.  You should post your other way as a solution and accept it, then, so anyone searching a similar problem can get the benefit of that answer.

Comment: @Dathan I did just waiting the 2 day waiting period for the acceptance.

Answer (score 1):

If you can modify the SQL you are using to retrieve the data do something like..

```
Select isnull(MyColumn,'No') as MyColumn
```

Comment: Ahh sorry, re-read your question and notice my mistake. Dathan's answer above should suit better.

Answer (score 1):

This is easily done without modifying data first. You can bind directly to your checkbox, then in **DataBindings | Advanced** you can specify what to use for a null value.

Sorry, I did not notice you needed to convert varchar Yes and No. Dathan's answer will get your data correctly, but I'm pretty sure you are going to have to manually update the values with a custom save method.

Comment: But how do a bind a string "Yes" and "No" to a bool for binding with the checked attribute from within the Advanced menu?

Answer (score 1):

This code converts the string into a bool? that can be used. Nullabe types have a 'HasValue' property that indicates if they are null or not.

```
public bool TryParseNullableBool (string value, out bool? result)
{
  result = false;
  if (string.IsNullOrEmpty (value))
  {
    result = null;
    return true;
  }
  else
  {
    bool r;
    if (bool.TryParse (value, out r))
    {
      result = r;
      return true;
    }
  }
  return false;
}
```

Comment: I like it, I can put that logic on the RowChanged event for loading and I can do the reverse for writes.

Comment: I'd steer away from this approach - not because it doesn't work (it clearly does), but because it leaks persistence store artifacts into the business logic.  Whenever possible, you should try to have your IO logic take responsibility for translating from data model to object model.  Implementing the above seems like a small sacrifice to make (and it is, in this case), but it doesn't tend to scale well.  If in your business logic you're always going to use the field as a boolean, then it should BE a boolean at every point where exposed to business logic.