# Using DataGridView with a BindingList<T> where T is an interface and cross-thread updates

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, datagridview, multithreading

When I have an interface something like this:

```
public interface IClass
{
    string { get; set;}
}
```

And a class that inherits the interface:

```
using System.Runtime.CompilerServices;

public class MyClass : INotifyPropertyChanged : IClass
{
    private string name;

    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

    public string Name
    {
        get { return name;}
        set
        {
            name = value;
            this.NotifyPropertyChanged();
        }
    }    

    public MyClass(string name)
    {
        this.Name = name;
    }

    private void NotifyPropertyChanged([CallerMemberName] string caller = "")
    {
        if (PropertyChanged != null)
        {
            PropertyChanged(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(caller));
        }
    }
}
```

And I bind a DataGridView datasource to a BindingList as follows:

```
BindingList<MyClass> classes = new BindingList<MyClass>();

MyClass testClass = new MyClass("test1");
MyClass testClass = new MyClass("test2");
classes.Add(testClass);

dataGridView1.DataSource = classes;
```

The datagridview updates whenever the name property is changed from another form. However when I try to do the following, it doesn't work.

```
BindingList<IClass> classes = new BindingList<IClass>();

MyClass testClass = new MyClass("test");
MyClass testClass = new MyClass("test2");
classes.Add(testClass);

dataGridView1.DataSource = classes;
```

I may have traced the problem such that when I use the BindingList for IClass, PropertyChanged event is null when updates to property are made. However, using BindingList for MyClass it is not null. Why?

The idea is such that there may be MyClassA, MyClassB, etc which have the same properties that can be displayed in the datagridview.

Additional question: What if MyClass is run in a non-UI thread and updates are made. Do I have to keep a reference to the main form or the control for thread marshalling? Or is this just plain bad design?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: What happens if you inherit IClass from INotifyPropertyChanged interface?

Comment: If MyClass runs in a non-UI thread, you will have to use a SynchronizationContext as in this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15256690/bool-as-datasource-for-a-checkbox-bool-update-in-an-other-thread-than-the-one-i/15264829#15264829

Comment: Thanks for pointers. Answer was staring in my face!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your MyClass inherits from both INotifyPropertyChanged and IClass. That's why PropertyChanged event fires when you use MyClass in BindingList.

On the other hand, IClass doesn't inherit from INotifyPropertyChanged, so it doesn't have access to it's PropertyChanged event handler. That's why PropertyChanged event doesn't fire when you use IClass in BindingList.

Try changing the order of inheritance like this.

```
public interface IClass : INotifyPropertyChanged 
    {
        string Name { get; set;}
    }


public class MyClass: IClass
    {
        private string name;

        public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

        public string Name
        {
            get { return name; }
            set
            {
                name = value;
                this.NotifyPropertyChanged("Name");
            }
        }

        public MyClass(string name)
        {
            this.Name = name;
        }

        private void NotifyPropertyChanged(string caller = "")
        {
            if (PropertyChanged != null)
            {
                PropertyChanged(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(caller));
            }
        }
```

I tested it. It works.

Comment: That was a simple solution. Wasted a few hours barking up the wrong tree. I blame the lack of sleep. Thanks!